# How can I detect my keyboard without press enter C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, key, detection

How can i change this code to active detecion of my keyboard. Now it is showing what i write after press enter. How can i show what i can write without enter key.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Width="300" Height="20">
   Type some text into the TextBox and press the Enter key.
  </TextBlock>
  <TextBox Width="300" Height="30" Name="textBox1"
           KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler"/>
  <TextBlock Width="300" Height="100" Name="textBlock1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = "You Entered: " + textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Or maybe is some diffrent way to create it?

Comment: Mh... what are you attempting to do?! Because this is not going to save what you previously typed...

Answer (score 1):

You could simply bind the text directly:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Width="300" Height="20">
   Type some text into the TextBox and it will appear in the field automatically.
  </TextBlock>
  <TextBox Width="300" Height="30" Name="textBox1" />
  <TextBlock Width="300" Height="100" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=textbox1}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This way you don't need any code-behind.

**EDIT**

If you want more sophisticated stuff, try this. Implement a new class in your project like this:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return $"You entered: {value ?? "nothing"}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

and then change your binding to

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="txtEdit" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ElementName=txtEdit}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Don't forget the resources for the window.

Here is a screen video showing it in action:

[image: Screen-Video]

Comment: True, but result won't appear until focus is **lost** on textbox

Comment: It will if you use UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged. I‘ll rework the sample when I‘m back home.

Comment: That's what I was nudging you to do ;)

Comment: Ok i have somethink what i want.                                                                                `  private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
                textBlock1.Text = Convert.ToString(e.Key);
        } `    Thanks everyone for help :D

Comment: @MickyD I just recognized that `UpdateSourceTrigger` is not approrpiate here because the `Text`-property of the TextBlock is not interactive which means you don't need it. It works on my machine with the edit I made.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBlock1.Text = "You Entered: " + **textBox1.Text**;
```

**Don't** use direct control property, in contrast use *MVVM* and binding.

"The UpdateSourceTrigger property of a binding controls how and when a changed value is sent back to the source."

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-update-source-trigger-property/

Comment: I think you are on the right path.  You might want to explain more that by using this particular binding updates happen immediately, no enter nor tabbing required

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood the question, you need tunneling [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown) event:

```
private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.G)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can you use [Keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard) class. In fact, Keyboard class can be used **anywhere** in your code:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Release left Ctrl button");
        return;
    }
    //Do other work
}
```